# Input-Format in Excel-VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for a function in Excel-VBA that converts a user-input of the form "**hhmm**" in the input-cell to the form "**hh:mm**" and checks for pausibility.

Any solution is welcome...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```vb
Dim InputText As String
Dim TextDate  As String
Dim TrueDate  As Date

InputText = "1749"
TextDate = Left(InputText, 2) & "\:" & Right(InputText, 2)
If IsDate(TextDate) Then
    TrueDate = CDate(TextDate)
    ' TrueDate -> #17:49#
End If
```

Now, set the format of the cell holding the value to `hh:nn`.

Comment: irst of all "thank you" for your answer!
But the basic transformation was already clear to me - I probably didn't ask my question precisely enough.
The goal of the task is to enter "hhmm" into a certain cell in the form - then to process the transformation and check - finally to insert the result in the same cell.
My idea here is to trigger the function when the cell is "exited" ;-)

Comment: I don't know your scenario, but if that would work for you, go ahead.